# how to open google map in fragment using custom navigation drawer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have used the following codings:

1. For Custom Navigation Drawer:
   http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/
2. For Google Map:
   http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-with-photos-at-any-location-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/

I'm new in android so please tell me how to link the the custom navigation drawer with google map.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.joellipman.com/articles/google/android/application-development/android-os-add-googlemap-as-fragment.html

Comment: @kevin guaun sir..actually i have already implement seperately google map in fragment and custom navigation drawer (added items like Caffe,Hospital,Bars etc) and now i just want to combined both so that i can get location of my near places in map by clicking on each place in drawer

Comment: Okay, any problem about my edit?

Comment: this ws about map on fragment..i dnt knw how to link both navigation and map

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't get the answer for this question. If you post your code, i can be more helpful. but, for now, I think you need to call MapFragment in your NavigationDrawer Activity.

If you need the map only for one fragment, I suggest you to use a switch statement.

Following shows a sample code.

```
 private void updateDisplay(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new MapFragment();
                break;

            case 1:
                fragment = any of your fragment();
                break;

            case 2:
                fragment = any of your fragment();
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            setTitle(menutitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLenear);
        }
        else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("Extract", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.